# How to make a program which run from shell still live after close terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, emacs, nohup, background-process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I prevent a script from terminating when the shell exits?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25690/how-do-i-prevent-a-script-from-terminating-when-the-shell-exits)

I use gnome-terminal, and I run `emacs` under the terminal in the background by executing `emacs &`, but after I close the terminal, `emacs` is also closed. How can I avoid this behavior? I know that `emacs` is a child process of the shell.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479/keep-ssh-sessions-running-after-disconnection and many other similar questions you can find here.

Answer (score 3):

Check out GNU Screen. You can run something in the screen, then detach and disconnect and the script/program continues to run.

Link: http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/

Screen can be found in most distros. Ubuntu has a forked "Super" version of it available as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can start `emacs` using the `nohup` command. `nohup` will run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty

`nohup emacs &`

This will prevent the `emacs` process from terminating when the shell closes and the controlling terminal is destroyed.

You can get more information about `nohup` from `info coreutils 'nohup invocation'`

This is a nice [discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and) about `nohup`, `disown`, and `&`.